# arcgis javascript how can i turn off layers

Tags: javascript, arcgis

i am doing the tutorial for displaying the map in a web browser 
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/intro_agstemplate_amd.html

now I have the code, what if I don't want to display all the layers, and want to turn off the first layer?

i can do it by index of the layer, or can i use the layer name?

trying to understand  i got to https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer-amd.html   but not sure how to use javascript

thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to turn off and on layers manually, I would use the layerlist widget script [LayerList widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/widget_layerlist_basic.html) 
or if you need the option to reorder the layers with the ability to turn layers on or off manually I would use the [Reorder layers in map service](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/layers_dynamic_reorder.html)

Comment: i like the layerlistwidget,   what if my map have 5 layers in my arcgis online  and I want to show to certain user just layer 1, and other users layer 2 and so on,  how can I tell:  don't show the widget (since I don't want the users to turn on and off layers)  and turn off layers 2 to 5, so they only see layer 1,    or  I need to do a map for each layer?  and depending the user is the map they will get?

Comment: Since you want the user to have no control on the map, I would then do a map for each layer and set permissions based on each group of user to see the map layer that they need to see